# Polygons from lines with manually completed lines using vertex tool and snapping

Tags: qgis, contour, vertices, polygonize

I have a vector layer of lines (contours) which was a model output. Some contours are incomplete due to land barriers (necessary for the model) which produces something like this

[image]

I have used the vertex tool with snapping turned on to complete these lines in order to produce polygon layers so I can fill the contours which produces:

[image]

However, when using lines to polygons, there are joins across from the new vertices rather than creating the polygon as a continuous shape which also ignores the smaller contour:

[image]

Is there a way to do this so the manual vertex joins produce a single polygon rather than this bisection from new vertex to new vertex? I tried using Polygonize which does produce the desired result visually but,

[image]

it doesn't seem to retain the data of the original lines so I cannot assign styles based on contour features with the new polygons. This is a watered down version of the actual model output so individually assigning polygons to contour data is not practically feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Try Dissolve - Multipart to Singleparts - Lines to polygons